# Can ffmpeg and libav headers coexist on Ubuntu? And aren't these headers #includeing each other wrongly?

Tags: c, ubuntu, ffmpeg

So Ubuntu has rejected ffmpeg in favour of its fork libav. I need to develop an app on Ubuntu which uses ffmpeg instead of libav.

I have compiled and linked ffmpeg separately and it seems to be ok but I've just realised I can't debug it properly because the system headers are for libav.

I've tried putting the ffmepg headers in a local path and doing e.g.

```
#include <ffmpeg-0.8.10/avformat.h>
```

instead of

```
#include <avformat.h>
```

but this gives me errors such as

```
ffmpeg-0.8.10/libavformat/avformat.h:455:10: error: use of enum ‘AVCodecID’ without previous declaration
```

`AVCodecID` is defined in avcodec.h but this is included from avformat.h as follows:

```
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
```

Two questions:

1. Can I set up the environment so that the local ffmpeg headers include each other correctly, without changing those headers, while libav headers are still installed and on the normal include path?
2. Am I crazy or shouldn't `#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"` always fail anyway because it will look for libavformat/libavcodev/avcodec.h which never exists?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Phonon is a better choice of library for this program.